# How to apply pivot in below scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have below table

```
Name    Month   Year    Count
----------------------------
xxx     12      2012    24
xxx     1       2013    42
xxx     2       2013    23
yyy     12      2012    34
yyy     1       2013    12
yyy     2       2013    54
```

I would like to convert it into below format,

```
Name    Dec-12  Jan-13  Feb-13
--------------------------------
xxx     24      42      23
yyy     34      12      54
```

How to apply pivot?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SQL Server there are several ways that you can pivot the data from rows into columns.

If your values are limited or you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the values with a static pivot:

```
select name, [Dec_12], [Jan_13], [Feb_13]
from
(
  select name,
    left(datename(month, dateadd(month, month, 0) -1), 3) +'_'+right(cast(year as varchar(4)), 2) MY,
    [count]
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(count)
  for my in ([Dec_12], [Jan_13], [Feb_13])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c7bb/16).

Now, if you have an unknown number of values, then you will need to implement dynamic SQL to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(my) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select left(datename(month, dateadd(month, month, 0) -1), 3) +'_'+right(cast(year as varchar(4)), 2) my,
                         CAST(
                            CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
                            RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
                            '01'
                         AS DATETIME) fulldate
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    group by my, fulldate
                    order by fulldate 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select name,
                  left(datename(month, dateadd(month, month, 0) -1), 3) +''_''+right(cast(year as varchar(4)), 2) MY,
                  [count]
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(count)
                for my in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d98b/1).

This difference with this and the static version is if you need an unknown number of dates or want this to automatically update with new dates when they are available, this will return the new data without changing the code.

The result of both queries is:

```
| NAME | DEC_12 | JAN_13 | FEB_13 |
-----------------------------------
|  xxx |     24 |     42 |     23 |
|  yyy |     34 |     12 |     54 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    Name, 
    CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(Year AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear,
    [Count]
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT 
  Name,
  [12-2012] AS 'Dec-12', 
  [1-2013]  AS 'Jan-13', 
  [2-2013]  AS 'Feb-13'
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(  
   MAX([Count])
   FOR MonthYear IN([12-2012], 
                    [1-2013], 
                    [2-2013])
) AS p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41db5/1)

Comment: @Rachcha - What do you mean? This is static pivot, but I used a CTE, just for formatting the month and year fields into one field then selecting them with different aliases.

Comment: ok... I thought this was dynamic pivot where the number of pivoted columns is unknown. This is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT t.name
         , MAX(CASE
                 WHEN t.month=12 AND t.year = 2012
                   THEN count
                 ELSE NULL
               END) AS "Dec_12"
         , MAX(CASE
                 WHEN t.month=1 AND t.year = 2013
                   THEN count
                 ELSE NULL
               END) AS "Jan_13"
         , MAX(CASE
                 WHEN t.month=2 AND t.year = 2013
                   THEN count
                 ELSE NULL
               END) AS "Feb_13"
    FROM table t
GROUP BY t.name
;
```